# Monix Observable groupBy large number of keys without memory leaks

Tags: scala, monix

I try to perform splitting single `Observable` in Monix by key, then group up to last `n` events in every `GrouppedObservable` and send them for further processing. The problem is that number of keys to group on is possibly infinite and that causes memory leaks.

*Context of application*:

I have kafka stream with messages from many conversations. Each conversation has `roomId` and I want to group this id  to get collection of Observables, each containing only messages from single conversation.
Conversation rooms are usually short lived, i.e. new conversation is created with unique `roomId`, few dozens of messages is exchanged in short period of time, then conversation is closed. 
To avoid memory leaks I want to keep buffers of only 100-1000 most recent conversation, and drop older ones. So if an event comes from a long unseen conversation, it will be treated as new conversation, because buffer with its previous messages will be forgotten.

[groupBy](https://monix.io/api/3.0/monix/reactive/Observable.html#groupBy[K](keySelector:A=%3EK)(implicitkeysBuffer:monix.reactive.OverflowStrategy.Synchronous[Nothing]):monix.reactive.Observable[monix.reactive.observables.GroupedObservable[K,A]]) method in Monix has argument `keysBuffer` that specifies how to deal with key buffers.

I thought that specifying `keyBuffer` to [DropOld](https://monix.io/api/3.0/monix/reactive/OverflowStrategy$.html#DropOldextendsOverflowStrategy.Evicted[Nothing]withProductwithSerializable) strategy will allow me to achieve behavior I wanted.

Below is simplified version of described use case.

```
import monix.execution.Scheduler.Implicits.global
import monix.reactive._

import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.util.Random

case class Event(key: Key, value: String, seqNr: Int) {
  override def toString: String = s"(k:$key;s:$seqNr)"
}

case class Key(conversationId: Int, messageNr: Int)

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val fakeConsumer = Consumer.foreach(println)
    val kafkaSimulator = Observable.interval(1.millisecond)
      .map(n => generateHeavyEvent(n.toInt))

    val groupedMessages = kafkaSimulator.groupBy(_.key)(OverflowStrategy.DropOld(50))
      .mergeMap(slidingWindow)

    groupedMessages.consumeWith(fakeConsumer).runSyncUnsafe()
  }

  def slidingWindow[T](source: Observable[T]): Observable[Seq[T]] =
    source.scan(List.empty[T])(fixedSizeList)

  def fixedSizeList[T](list: List[T], elem: T): List[T] =
    (list :+ elem).takeRight(5)

  def generateHeavyEvent(n: Int): Event = {
    val conversationId: Int = n / 500
    val messageNr: Int = n % 5
    val key = Key(conversationId, messageNr)
    val value = (1 to 1000).map(_ => Random.nextPrintableChar()).toString()
    Event(key, value, n)
  }

}
```

However, observing  application heap on VisualVM indicates memory leak. After about 30 minutes of running, I got `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded`

Below are screenshot of heap usage plots depicting running my app for about 30 minutes. (Flattened part in the end is after `OutOfMemoryError`)

[VisualVM Heap plot of application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpliG.png)

My question is: **How can I group events in monix by possibly infinite number of keys without leaking memory? Old keys are allowed to be dropped**

Background info:

- monix version: `3.0.0-RC2`
- scala version: `2.12.8`

Comment: Wouldn't you want to `groupBy(_.key.conversationId)` instead of `_.key`?

Comment: Might be related: https://github.com/monix/monix/issues/393

Answer (score 2):

I have similar use case like yours, reading kafka stream and grouping by id.

What you want to do, is to timeout/cleanup the `GrouppedObservable` when there is no demand. Otherwise, it will sit in memory forever. So, you can do something like this:

```
val eventsStream: Observable[Int] = ???

eventsStream
  .groupBy(_ % 2 == 0)
  .mergeMap {
    _.mapEval(s => Task.delay(println(s)))
     .timeoutOnSlowUpstreamTo(5.minutes, Observable.empty)
  }
  .completedL
```